# How do I parse the phrase "it stands to reason"?

Tags: ambiguity, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

In the phrase "*it stands to reason that...*", is *reason* a verb or a noun?

If it is a verb, it is subordinate to the verb *stands*, which is being used metaphorically:

> it is sound/stable for one to reason that...

On the other hand, used as a noun, I imagine that reason is a synecdoche for the principles of logic and rationality, or something like that, and that *to stand to reason* is to withstand any logical rebuke from this capital-R Reason.

I feel these mean two slightly different things, and in either case, they correspond to different parse trees, so which is more accurate to the original/proper usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression and reason is a noun:

***[it stands to reason](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/it-stands-to-reason):***

​

> said when something is obvious or clear from the facts:
>
> - *If 20 percent of the earth's population has 80 percent of its resources, then it stands to reason that 80 percent of the population has only 20 percent of the resources.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***Stand to:***

> it’s a reminder of an obsolete phrase “to stand to,” meaning (in the OED’s words) ‘To submit oneself to, abide by (a trial, award); to obey, accede to, be bound by (another’s judgement, decision, opinion, etc.).’ So originally something “stood to (obeyed) reason” in the same way as a person “stood to a judgment”; when the verbal phrase was eroded by time, the cliché remained behind.

(www.wordorigins.org)

Comment: Please edit to note that the quote is actually from [Language Hat](http://languagehat.com/stands-to-reason/), and only cited in the wo.o post you found it in ...

Comment: The OP is expected to do as much of homework though.

Answer (score 0):

Think of "It stands to reason" as "It holds up to logical scrutiny/rational consideration". It's being used as a noun.